# android swipe progress bar Notification don't work

Tags: java, android, notifications

am trying to make a progress bar Notification and everything is working perfect
but the problem is that i can't cancel the notification
and everytime i swipe it 
it comes again
and the progress bas is duplicating when i start it again before the last one finish the progress
so what can i do in this situation ?

the Notification code

```
private void startNotification() {
        String value= mEditTextInput.getText().toString();
        final int input2=Integer.parseInt(value);
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(Notification.this, Notification.class);
        final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Notification.this,
                0, activityIntent, 0);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Notification.this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti)
                .setContentTitle("title")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setColor(Color.BLUE)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setProgress(input2, 0, false);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemClock.sleep(0);

                for (int progress = 0; progress <= input2; progress += 1) {
                    notification.setProgress(input2, progress, false);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
                notification.setContentText("finish")
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                        .setOngoing(false)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setColor(Color.RED);
                ;

                notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: check whether your `input2` is positive value

Comment: try.`setOngoing(true)` instead .of `setOngoing(false)`

Comment: if i set setOngoing(true) i can not dismiss the notification until it finish and the timer is about 1 hour and yes the input2 has positive value. when i set setOngoing (false) the notification return immediately when i swipe it. i just want to know how can i cancel the progress immediately without waiting until it finish..thank you sir